# How to optimise this short and simple code (includes a best practice question)

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a question I frequently ask myself. Here is a code with no repeated code:

```
private static void delete(Guid teamID, Guid repID)
{
    using (var context = AccesDataRépart.GetNewContext())
    {
        Team_Representant teamRepresentant = getTeamRep(teamID, repID);
        if (teamRepresentant != null)
            context.Team_Representant.DeleteOnSubmit(teamRepresentant);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

private static Team_Representant getTeamRep(Guid teamID, Guid repID)
{
    using (var context = AccesDataRépart.GetNewContext())
    {
        return (from c in context.Team_Representant
                where c.RepID == repID &&
                      c.TeamID == teamID
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

It is normal to have a `getTeamRep` function, it is used very often. On the other hand, I don't repeat the query it contains in the `Delete` function because it would generate extra steps and would generally be slower.

What do you do in such case? Do you repeat the `getTeamRep` linq query in the `Delete` function or do you accept this extra workload?

Thanks!

Comment: Static methods? Is this a repository? Or web service?

Comment: Can you give us some extra context?

Comment: It is static because it's a data access class. Not a web service, but close to. Now I don't understand why it's rated -1. The question is short and clear so I don't waste people's time with unnecessary infos.

Comment: Then you probably want to make the context variable an instance variable. Then all the operations are done with one context. Google Unit of Work and Repository pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never do anything twice :).  Make a variable to hold the result of getTeamRep.

If you've never tried it before, get rid of your static stuff and make these all instance methods.  Have a Team class and a Rep class, and let the Teams contain their Reps.  It might be more fun this way, and it tends to prevent the whole problem of looking up the same object twice.

It's a matter of preference.  I find instance methods more elegant in most cases, because there are fewer parameters:

```
 Team team = new Team(teamID);

 team.Delete(repID);
```

Comment: I never thought of it this way, but I like that. I will definitly follow this idea on my next app (this one is almost finished). Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to add, that the way I suggested in the example above, if you implement the IEnumerable interface (or better) on the Team class, will let you do data binding in .NET, which will automatically let you display, for instance the reps in each team on a Report, a WinForm or WebForm, a WPF control, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I will digg this out for sure!